# Javascript project manager?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am building a game in HTML5 and JavaScript.

Is there any sort of software that can manage things such as revisions and a changelog?

If not, what do you guys do to manage your projects?

Comment: Manage revisions? You mean like GIT, Subversion, CVS, Perforce ...etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GitHub.com. You can create a free account and track all of your revisions.

Answer (score 0):

You might try [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) with [mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial), which is what I use.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Code](http://code.google.com/hosting/) provides free open-source project hosting using Git, Subversion, or Mercurial, and provides an issue tracker, wiki pages, and downloads.

Answer (score 0):

It's not any different than any other codebase from a project management perspective.  Any source control system, or issue tracking system will work just as well with a javascript project as it would with any other kind of software project.

You are thinking about your question the wrong way if you think that "building a game in HTML5 and JavaScript" would be something that might affect the answer.

Comment: Honestly I didn't know what to expect, as this is the first major coding project I've done.